# singularity extract, edit, and rebuild image

Tags: singularity-container, squashfs

I have a singularity container that has been made for me (to run tensorflow on comet GPU nodes) but I need to modify the keras install for my purposes.

I understand that `.simg` files are not editable (and that the writable `.img` format is deprecated), so the process of converting to an `.img` file, editing, and then converting back to `.simg` is discouraged:

```
sudo singularity build --writable development.img production.simg
## make changes
sudo singularity build production2.img development.simg
```

It seems to me the best way might be to extract the contents (say into a *sandbox*), edit them, and then rebuild the sandbox into an `.simg` image.

I know how to do the second conversion (`singularity build new-sif sandbox`), but how can I do the first?

I have tried the following, but the command never finishes:

```
sudo singularity build tf_gpu tensorflow-gpu.simg
WARNING: Authentication token file not found : Only pulls of public images will succeed
Build target already exists. Do you want to overwrite? [N/y] y
2018/10/12 08:39:54 bufio.Scanner: token too long
INFO:    Starting build...
```

Answer (score 8):

You can easily convert between a sandbox and a production build using the following:

```
sudo singularity build lolcow.sif docker://godlovedc/lolcow  # pulls and builds an example container

sudo singularity build --sandbox lolcow_sandbox/ lolcow.sif # converts from container to a writable sandbox

sudo singularity build lolcow2 lolcow_sandbox/ # converts from sandbox to container
```

So, you can edit the sandbox and then rebuild accordingly.

Comment: Note that in general you'll need superuser permissions when invoking `singularity build`. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/68176610 . I prefixed the invocations with `sudo` in your answer.