# How do I add an additional command line tool to an already existing Docker/Singularity image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-container, singularity-container

I work in neuroscience, and I use a cloud platform called Brainlife to upload and download data (linked [here](https://brainlife.io/), but I don't think knowledge of Brainlife is relevant to this question). I use Brainlife's command line interface to upload and download data on my university's server. In order to use their CLI, I run Singularity with a Docker image created by  Brainlife (found [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/brainlife/cli)). I run this using the following code:

```
singularity shell docker://brainlife/cli -B
```

I also have the file saved on my server account, and can run it like this:

```
singularity shell brainlifeimage.sif -B
```

After running one of those commands, I am able to download and upload data, usually successfully. Currently I'm following Brainlife's tutorial to bulk download data. The tutorial uses the command line tool "jq" ([link](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)), which isn't on their docker image. I tried installing it within the Singularity shell like this:

```
apt-get install jq
```

And it returned:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: Unable to locate package jq
```

Is there an easy way to add this one tool to the image? I've been reading over the Singularity and Docker documentations, but Docker is all new to me and I'm really lost.

If relevant, my university server runs on Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS, and I am using terminal on a Mac laptop running MacOS 11.3. This is my first stack overflow question - please let me know if i can provide any additional info! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short, specific answer: `jq` is portable, so you can just mount it into the image and use it normally. *e.g.,*

```sh
singularity shell -B /path/to/jq:/usr/bin/jq brainlifeimage.sif
```

The short, general answer: you can't modify the read only image and need to build a new one.

---

Long answer with several options and specific examples:

Since singularity images are read only, they cannot have persistent changes made to them. This is great for reproducibility, a bit inconvenient if your tools are likely to change often. You can rebuild the image in several ways, though all will require `sudo` permissions.

1. Write a new Singularity definition based on the docker image

Create a new definition file (generally called `Singularity` or `something.def`), use the current container as a base and add the desired software in the `%post` section. Then build the new image with: `sudo singularity build brainy_jq.sif Singularity`

The [definition file docs](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.8/user-guide/definition_files.html) are quite good and highly recommended.

```
Bootstrap: docker
From: brainlife/cli:latest

%post
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y jq
```

2. Create a sandbox of the current singularity image, make your changes, and convert back to a read-only image. See the singularity docs on [writable sandbox directories](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.8/user-guide/build_a_container.html#creating-writable-sandbox-directories) and [converting images between formats](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.8/user-guide/build_a_container.html#converting-containers-from-one-format-to-another).

```sh
# use --sandbox to create a writable singularity image
sudo singularity build --sandbox writable_brain/ brainlifeimage.sif
# --writable must still be used to make changes, and sudo for correct permissions
sudo singularity exec writable_brain/ bash -c 'apt-get update && apt-get install -y jq'
# convert back to read-only image for normal usage
sudo singularity build brainlifeimage_jq.sif writable_brain/
```

3. Modify the source docker image locally and build from that. One of the more... *creative* options. Almost sudo-free, except `singularity pull` doesn't accept `docker-daemon` so a `sudo singularity build` is necessary.

```sh
# add jq to a new docker container. the value for --name doesn't matter, but we use it
# in later steps. The entrypoint needs to be overridden in this case as well.
docker run -it --name brainlife-jq --entrypoint=/bin/bash \
    brainlife/cli:1.5.25 -c 'apt-get update && apt-get install -y jq'

# use docker commit to create an image from the container so it can be reused
# note that we're using the name of the image set in the previous step
# the output of docker commit is the hash for the newly created image, so we grab that
IMAGE_ID=$(docker commit brainlife-jq)

# tag the newly created image with a more useful name
docker tag $IMAGE_ID brainlife/cli:1.5.25-jq

# here we use docker-daemon instead of docker to build from a locally cached docker image
# instead of looking at docker hub
sudo singularity build brainlife_jq.sif docker-daemon://brainlife/cli:1.5.25-jq

# now check that it all worked as planned
singularity exec brainlife_jq.sif which jq
# /usr/bin/jq
```

ref: [docker commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/), [using locally cached docker images](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.8/user-guide/singularity_and_docker.html#locally-available-images-cached-by-docker)